# Pass the request parameter across all the URLs

Tags: laravel

Currently building a laravel app where I am required to pass a parameter value across all the URL.
For example, if I have a request from a user with ?utm-source="app" I need to pass that parameter on every url that user browses. For example, if a user is in domain.com?utm-source="app" and then clicks on /news/123 then I need to ensure it is loaded through /news/123?utm-source="app". And if the user is on domain.com/?utm-source="app" and clicks on page /news/123?limit=3, then it should be going to  /news/123?limit=3&utm-source="app".

I appreciate any kind of suggestions or implementation of middleware in my case.
Thank you!

Comment: Are UTM parameters the actual use case, or just an example? I ask, because Google Analytics already handles this for you; they store in the session on Google's end. If it's just an example, sessions are what you need to look in to.

Comment: Hi @ceejayoz, this is not for tracking but actually for an app-level feature.

Comment: OK, and making it work with session data is not an option?

Comment: Nope, I'm loading the webpage in a web view via React Native and there is no guarantee every device has access to session storage.